# Why am I getting a fatal memory error on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I get the following error when I try to open the sitemap.xml of my WordPress blog:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1052672 bytes) in /xxx/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/sitemaps/class-taxonomy-sitemap-provider.php on line 131
```

Link to the Sitemap: https://dooiz.com/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: How can we know what is happening, without seeing any code?
Are you the developer of this dooiz website?

Comment: If you have a lot of items that you're trying to load the sitemap for, 256M memory may not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually pretty obvious. You have to increase the memory limit of your webspace.

Write this in your wp-config under the debug line:

```php
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
```

you could also try writing the following in the .htaccess file

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Or ask your webspace provider how and if you can increase the memory limit.